# Windows Phone IsolatedStorageSettings lists

Tags: c#, windows, list, windows-phone-8

I have only one simple question. I saved a string List to my IsolatedStorageSettings but I have no idea how I can read them.
Can you help me?

```
IsolatedStorageSettings episodename = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
List<string> episodelist = new List<string>();
episodelist.Add(Beschreibung);
episodename.Add("test", episodename);
episodename.Save();
```

Beschreibung and episodename are two strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings episodename = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
List<string> read = null;
if (episodename.Contains("test")) read = (List<string>)episodename["test"];
```

Apart from that you have also mistake in your code:

```
episodename.Add("test", episodename); // this line should be:
episodename.Add("test", episodelist);
```

In other case you will get an exception as it's hard to serialize `IsolatedStorageSettings` class.

Comment: episodename is the IsolatedStorageSettings but episodelist is the List.

Comment: @user3022024 Yes that's right. But as I think you want to save your list rather than ISS. See your code you have posted, try to run it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right I make a mistake. I interchange episodename and episodelist. Thank you. I find some Problem in my Code before when i fix them I can give you a Feedback for your code.

Answer (score 0):

I get my values from IsolatedStorageSettings like this:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings episodename = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
List<string> episodelist;
if (episodename.TryGetValue("test", out episodelist))
{     
      // Do something with episodelist
}
```